# How to approach Django project starting with database schema?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

Every Django tutorial/book I've seen approaches Django projects from what I am going to characterize as an ad-hoc database design method.  A project ends-up being a bunch of little apps, each with it's own models, view, etc.

I am trying to locate a resource that covers how to structure a Django project when you do, in fact, start with a traditional DB design process.

For example, let's say that this is the starting point:

[image]

And a document describing it:

[LEAD Database Guide](http://geneontology.org/page/lead-database-guide)

How does one approach this so that the various Django apps access a single "global" (bad word) db model that covers the entire schema rather than a bunch of models spread across a bunch of apps?

Are there any resources (books, pdf's, tutorials) that cover this approach rather than the piece-meal approach most commonly seen?

A corollary to this question might be:  Is there a, perhaps automated, way to go from an SQL (or MySQL Workbench) schema definition to the equivalent Django ORM?

Comment: Do you have the database already? Also, are you sure you can't split your logic into smaller chunks? Smaller or more specific apps help you create code that is easier to mantain. If you have the database created, just use inspectdb (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/) and you can put the output on a model file (A single one if you want to keep your big model).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the inspectdb command to generate models.py from database:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Then, you can treat the models as a single app, and add more features/tables into new apps in the future.

Comment: I'll take a look at this and get back to you.  I remember reading somewhere that this is not an ideal approach but rather a bandaid.  I don't know enough at this point to have a valid opinion.

Comment: It isn't an ideal approach, it is a starting point. It will give you a lot of what you need, but it is worth cleaning up the generated models to adhere to Django best practices. I've found it has gotten me about 90% of the way there, however.